# Guava / Voldemort / MySQL flushing to DB issue

Tags: java, mysql, guava, voldemort

Does anyone have experience when using Guava in front of voldemort (with the mysql storage option on the back-end) I have in-depth experience with MySQL but voldemort and guava are quite new to me.

I'm simulating writes through the system but cannot actually see all of the records in the mysql table after the writes complete. MySQL only seems to write about 80 to 90 % of the records I throw at Guava.

Subsequent reads in some cases get the records to flush into the backend mysql, but I was wondering if ther was better way to issue a flush command. (As a shutdown of the voildemort daemon won't issue a flush either)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!
C

Comment: Do you mean Google Guava? If yes, can you explain a bit *how* you are using Guava in front of Voldemort?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what eviction policy you defined. Guava will call back to your evictionListener.
Here are some of policy like expireAfterAccess, expireAferWrite, softKeys, softValues, weakKeys and weakValues.
We had used Guava as cache layer with backend of MySql and Postgres as persistence layer to store 1 Billions records of key/value. Since our performance requirement call for random read/write within 5 ms range. We had developed a CacheStore plug in for voldemort. Please check out http://code.google.com/p/cachestore/ to see whether it fits your need or not.